# Why is my integer value stored in a sqlite database limited to a integer 16?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, integer, nsnumber

I am trying to build an iPad application with Data Entities, linked to a sqlite database.

At a certain moment I am trying to store a numeric value, but my value gets messed up. The maximum value of the field seems to be 32.767 (small int), even though the database column type is an `INTEGER`.

**Code snippet:**

```
- (IBAction)saveValue:(UITextField *)sender {           

    switch (sender.tag) {
        case PRICE:
            _property.asked_price = [Converter textToNumber:sender.text];
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

**Converter.m**

```
+ (NSNumber *) textToNumber:(NSString *) value {
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setLocale: [NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [f setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber * tempNumber = [f numberFromString: value];
    [f release];

    return tempNumber;
}
```

So the `asked_price` property is declared as a `NSNumber` and the corresponding database field is an `INTEGER`.

Why is it only allowing me to store values up to 32,767 ? Anything bigger than that becomes some seemingly random value.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it Core Data or plain SQlite?

Comment: @MartinR I'm using Core Data. Your remark reminded me that I can configure this in the `.xcdatamodeld` file. And indeed it is listed as an `Integer 16` there. Problem now is that when I change it to 32, I cannot start my application anymore...

Comment: If the attribute is defined as "Integer 16", then all numbers are silently truncated to 16-bit in the managed object, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107787/nsnumber-what-to-be-aware-of-when-using-and-storing-different-primitive-types. You could try to change it to "Integer 32" and set the "lightweight migration" options when opening the persistent store.

Comment: @MartinR Great, I have just changed the type to an Integer 32. The reason it was crashing was that I had to remove the app from my simulator first, clean the project and it was fine. Tnx for pointing me into the right direction! It's been too long since I've last developed in in XCode...

Comment: If you've already published the application, you'll want to do what Martin R said. (with the lightweight migration).  Otherwise, your users apps will crash when they update... and *they* will had to delete and re-install.